# iterate though all class blocks using DOM

Tags: php, dom

I am scraping data from web page using  DOM classes.

There are various blocks of `div` each with review, image, date, rate etc.

Here is code which scrap data for particular class. But here it scrap data for first class only. How can I iterate so that I can get details from all classes?

Here is my code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html= file_get_contents('http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80');

$html = escapeshellarg($html) ;
$html = nl2br($html);

$classname = 'rating-qualifier';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}


$classname = 'review_comment ieSucks';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

$meta = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName("meta");
echo $meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
```

Output: http://codepad.viper-7.com/j0cTNi

**UPDATE**

http://codepad.viper-7.com/lHS9jk

Here I added :

```
$classname = 'review-wrapper';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

foreach($results as $node)
{
  // scrapping code here
}
```

But it scrap same class value during each iteration. SEee result : http://codepad.viper-7.com/lHS9jk

Comment: You're not looping in this code anywhere, then why do you expect it to get data from all classes?

Comment: @AmalMurali: Yes, but I dont know foreach should be applied on which element and how

Comment: `foreach ($results as $node) { echo $node->nodeValue; }`

Comment: @AmalMurali: sorry but I am not much familiar with `DOM`, here I used loop, but every time it prints same values only http://codepad.viper-7.com/lHS9jk

Comment: @AmalMurali: can you suggest what is mistake?